# How to use a general function pointer as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is it possible to use a general function pointer as a template parameter? The function pointer  template can accept free functions, member functions, and lambda functions. For simplicity, assuming the functions has only one argument, like

```
template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT, function* f>
struct A
{
   // f is used somewhere.
};
```

Comment: You can do that, but you will get different incompatible types for the different function type instantiations. That is, you cannot assign an A with a general function pointer to an A with a pointer to member function, even if ArgumentT and ReturnT are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A normal template argument can refer to a function.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ArgT, class RetT, class F>
struct A {
    F f;
public:
    A(F f) : f(f) {}

    RetT operator()(ArgT arg) { return f(arg); }
};

int unchanged(int i) { return i; }

int main(){
    A < int, int, int(*)(int)> t{ unchanged };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << t(i) << "\n";
}
```

There's nothing restricting the template argument to a function though -- you could just as easily use some class that overloads `operator()`, and invoke that instead (and, in fact, that's often preferable).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use std::function<> if you can use C++11 or boost::function<> if you cannot:

```
template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT > struct A { 
    typedef std::function< ReturnT( ArgumentT ) > Function;
    void foobar( Function f ) { ReturnT ret = f( arg ); }
};
```

In this case you can pass function pointer, functor, lambda, or use std::bind or boost::bind with almost any function which signature does not match. I am not sure you need template in this case, you can use std::function directly, but that depends on your code.

Comment: There are many downsides to using std::function, however, so this is not blanket advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're combining types and data, you want something more like:

```
template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT, typename F*>
struct A {
    //use F* to refer to f somewhere
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something close with:

```
template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT, class F, F f>
struct A;

template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT, ReturnT (*f)()>
struct A<ArgumentT, ReturnT, ReturnT (*)(), f>
{
   // f is used somewhere.
};

template<class ArgumentT, class ReturnT, class C, ReturnT (C::*f)()>
struct A<ArgumentT, ReturnT, ReturnT (C::*)(), f>
{
   // f is used somewhere.
};
```

...but you can't take something like a `std::function<ReturnT ()>` as a non-type template parameter. The specialisation for function pointers will also accept non-capturing lambdas.